# Shopify: Which LIQUID file needs to be edited to display a line of text below line items in the cart page?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, shopify, liquid

I'm looking for a way to alert customers to click "Update Shopping Cart". Here is the wording
Text: Changed any gift quantity? Click below to update your cart/subtotal. I need to place this where the redbox in the image below is. Could you please direct me to the LIQUID file that I can edit to bring this change? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the theme files? If you haven't done the gitHub integration check here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72TSwHEhfDs&t=503s

Comment: Thank you, I already fixed it by adding the text in the relevant cart related LIQUID file of the our them.